# Plotting a CSV with coordinates one row at a time via GeoPandas

Tags: python, csv, geopandas, shapely, pandas

I have a CSV of all earthquakes in my country for the last 10 years arranged by date and time. My goal is to plot each line chronologically one by one, so that I can compile these maps and produce a "time-lapse" of the earthquakes. The CSV is already sorted but I'll code the "sorting" function when I get there.

So if I have 10 earthquakes, the end products are 10 maps with each a single plot of where the earthquake happened.

My code:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r'path')

def plotPoint():
    df = pd.read_csv('earthquakes.csv')
    geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude'])]
    crs = "epsg:32651"
    gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
    basemap = gpd.read_file('basemap.shp')
    for i in range(len(gdf)): # Counts how many rows there are then loops through each line of "gdf"
        if i == 0: # Skips over first line since it is the column header
            continue
        pt = gdf.plot(ax=basemap.plot(figsize=(10,6)), marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)
        print(pt[i]) # Executes "pt" one line at a time
plotPoint()
```

When I run this, I get

```
File "C:\path\file.py", line 26, in plotPoint
    print(pt[i]) 
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm still new to Python. Any leads?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to indicate where the error occurs.

Comment: Done. Thank you for editing! @Vince

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following script saves an image for each earthquake point in a single plot.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

os.chdir(r'path')

def plotPoint():
    df = pd.read_csv('earthquakes.csv')
    basemap = gpd.read_file('basemap.shp')
    crs = "epsg:32651"
    geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude'])]
    gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

    for i in range(gdf.shape[0]):
        ax = basemap.plot(figsize=(10,6))
        g = gdf.iloc[i].geometry
        plt.plot(g.x, g.y, marker='o', color='red', markersize=15)
        plt.savefig("earthquake_{0}.png".format(i))

plotPoint()
```

Result: (Three plots in the image are separate and each plot is saved to current working directory as separate images)

[image]

Comment: Wow! This worked! You wrote the entire code. I'll understand each line in the for loop,  some of those things are new to me. Thank you!

Comment: That full code will be useful for me as well. Thank you!